# Cannot convert serial number to date and time format

Tags: excel, date, time, excel-2007

It's just as the title says, I cannot convert the serial numbers generated from the DATE and TIME function to a Date and Time Format.

I have this date: 27/11/2012 1:09 PM (originally typed in as text and not acknowledged as date and time, because it was aligned to the left). So instead, I decided to use the DATE and TIME function like so:

```
=(DATE(2014,8,26) & TIME(13,27,0))
```

It resulted with a serial number. So I googled on ways how to convert the serial number to a date format. OF course, I already tried formatting a cell by right-clicking it and selecting the Date category but still no luck.

Now that I think about it, is the formula above alright? I mean is it okay to use date and time in one cell?  By the way, the dates and times were manually typed in in one cell. And I do not have an option to segregate each date and time elements per cell.

UPDATE: So I tried doing it with just the DATE function only and the formatting worked. Is there any way that even the time is included?

Comment: Use **+** rather then **&**

Answer (score 0):

```
=(DATE(2014,8,26) + TIME(13,27,0))
```

Use "+" for date and time concord-nation :)

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some _context_, explaining _how_ it works and _when_ to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.